# Installing Cisco VPN Client on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

I've been googling for this for a while now, both for the client itself and a guide how to install the client, with little success.

How can I install the Cisco VPN client on Linux, and where can I get it from?

I have Ubuntu 9.04 and It is stated to be Cisco VPN supported. But when I import the PCF file I get an Error: `there were no valid VPN secrets`

Answer (score 2):

This has since been answered on our Ubuntu-specific sister site Ask Ubuntu:

> ## [How do I install Cisco VPN client?](https://askubuntu.com/q/31100/36499)
>
> What is best way to install the Cisco VPN client application in Ubuntu?

There were a lot of low-quality answers and speculation on this post, so I'm going to lock it. Follow the instructions over on Ask Ubuntu, and if you have problems with it, you can always ask for help in a new question here on Super User or on Ask Ubuntu.